# how to put tags in articles in python django in website

Tags: python, django, web

my client want me to build an article post website in which the user come and login and write the articles.in article he must put tags and with those tags the other users can search. the problem is i do not know how to put tags in views. and also in html .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyvay.png)

and my views file is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RyLh.png)

can any body please help me with sample coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple third party app that can help you with tagging. It's called **django-taggit** and you can find how to easily set it up it in its [Documentation page](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or by following this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnFCdWQbryo).

Basically, you need to install it with `pip install django_taggit`, add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and add the manager to the desired model, for example:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model): 
    # ...
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Then just create a migration for your model changes with `python manage.py makemigrations post` followed by `python manage.py migrate`. 
Now you can add, remove or list the tags with simple commands:

```
post.tags.add('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3') # add tags
post.tags.remove('tag1') # remove tags
post.tags.all() # list tags
```